# How to automatically playback commit detail from a specific commit backward?

Tags: git

What I want is:

given a start commit `p`,

do the following:

```
git show p
```

and if finished reading and then press `ENTER`,automatically show the previous commit.

Until I press ctrl-c to terminate .

Is there a tool to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but the following is quite straight forward since `<commit>~n` designates the nth ancestor from a commit:

```
$ git checkout p
read...
$ git checkout p~1
read...
$ git checkout p~2
etc.
```

A small scripting effort will lead to the behavior you describe, though.

Comment: Yes, I think scripting is necessary here, the basic problem is how to get the previous version of `p` ?

Comment: `p~1`, as stated is in the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git log --format=%h $commit | while read hash; do git show $hash; echo -n Press enter to continue; read dummy; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you're asking for, but there's a git command to play back the commit history of a given file: [git playback](https://github.com/jianlius/git-playback)